# Compile twice in django_tex

Tags: django, compilation, latex, pdflatex, tableofcontents

I need to compile a `.tex` file twice with `django_tex` in order for the table of contents to load correctly. Is there a way to tell the interpreter in `django_tex` to run the compiler twice (I use `pdflatex`)??

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}


\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
Introduction text.

\section{Second section}
Second section text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django_tex` seems to support latexmk, which will (amongst many other useful things, like running bibliography tools) automatically determine the required number of *tex runs.

To use this, you can follow the advice from https://github.com/weinbusch/django-tex/pull/5#issuecomment-447030408 and add

```
LATEX_INTERPRETER='latexmk -pdf'
```

to your `settings.py`.